# How to reduce font size/command area in lwuit?

Tags: lwuit, lwuit-form, lwuit-textarea, lwuit-button

In LWUIT..how do you reduce the command area size (The area at the bottom of the screen where the commands are added).

Basically , I wish to reduce the font size of the command text and the size of the command area along with it.

Also, in general how to reduce the font size of the entire text in the LWUIT application at once rather than doing it for each component separately?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the theme in the Codename One Designer or Resource Editor and click the default entry. Edit the font size to small.

To do this only for the softkey and a SoftButton style.